Mapping relativistic operators to non-relativistic ones
I am learning about NREFTs with respect to dark matter. I have been following this paper. On page 48, they give a dictionary between the relativistic and the non-relativistic reduction of certain operators.
For the simple case of $\bar{\chi}\chi\bar{N}N$ it is straight forward that we need to expand the Dirac spinors, to their non-relativistic form yielding the following expression.
\begin{equation}
U_\chi(p)=\sqrt{\frac{E+m}{2 m}}\binom{\xi_\chi}{\frac{\vec{\sigma} \cdot \vec{p}}{E+m_\chi} \xi_\chi} \sim\binom{\xi_\chi}{\frac{\vec{\sigma} \cdot \vec{p}}{2 m_\chi} \xi_\chi}
\end{equation}
Plugging in the the operator above it is straight forward to see that up to leading order in momenta, $\bar{\chi}\chi\bar{N}N \mapsto 4 1_{\chi}\cdot 1_{N}$. Nonetheless I struggle to derive the expression for the operator
\begin{equation}
P^\mu \bar{\chi} \chi \bar{N} i \sigma_{\mu \alpha} q^\alpha N.
\end{equation}
According to the aforementioned paper the result should be of the form
\begin{equation}
-\left(4 m_\chi^2\right) q^2+16 m_N m_\chi^2 i v^{\perp} \cdot\left(q \times S_N\right)
\end{equation}
where $q$ is the momentum transfer, and $v^{\perp} = (P/m_x+K/m_N)$, for $P$ and $K$ the the sum of the momenta for before and after the scattering of the $x$ and $N$ particle respectively.
If somebody could give certain hints, I will be thankful.
